# Is the parametric form of functions that solve a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation unique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For exposition purposes, let's say I have the following second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation:
$$\frac{-f''}{f'}-\frac{1}{y-w}-a=0$$
Where $a,w\in\pmb{R}_+$. The solution given to me by [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=-Divide%5By%27%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cy%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%3DDivide%5B%5C%2840%291%2Ba%5C%2840%29x-b%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2Cx-b%5D) (please excuse my laziness) is:

$$f(y)=\int_1^{y}exp\bigg(\int_{1}^{\phi}\frac{a(\rho-w)+1}{w-\rho}d\rho\bigg)c_1d\phi+c_2$$

Is this solution unique? In other words, does it exist functions with a different parametric form that solve this equation?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint. $\ln(y')'+\ln(y-w)'+(a y)'=0$

Comment: $f$ should be $y$, right?

Comment: Thank you @Cesareo! I think I got the hint. From this reformulation, one would obtain something like this: $f(y)=e^{a^2-c_1}\int_{-\infty}^y\frac{e^{a(a-x)}}{a(a-x)}dx+c_2$. So yes, there are different parametric forms for a same ODE. I guess, my question is more about how can we find them all.